# Lost asp.net mvc tools

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

So, i've lost my asp.net mvc tools integrated into visual studio.

I have Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.NET MVC 3.

For example, when i r-clicked before into controller action method, i had in a pop-up menu rows with values like 'Add View, Go to View' or when i r-clicked on Views folder i had 'Add view' row too, but now, i don't have it at all in my project.

If i create new project and trying to do what i've written upper- everything fine, all rows in pop-up menu here and works, but in my current- it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I've found answer to my question. That's after I deleted `'ProjectTypeGuids' = {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};` in Unload and edit project. Very nice :)